# Splitting input one by one and translating input one by one using functions in JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, function

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

   <head lang="en">
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />
    <script type="application/javascript" src="js/client.js"></script>
   <title>A simple translation app</title>
     </head>

   <body>
   <h1>A simple tranlation app</h1>
 <div>
    <textarea id="sourceText">
   </textarea>
   </div>
   <div>
    <label for="translation">Choose:</label>
    <select id="translation" name="translation">
     <option value="englishToFrench">English to French</option>
     <option value="frenchToEnglish">French to English</option>
     </select>
    </div>
    <div>
    <textarea id="targetText" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
   </div>
      <div>
       <button id="translateBtn" type="button">Translate</button>
            </div>
              <div id="alert">
               </div>
```

The task here is for the user to input a certain english words in the object and translate them into french as follows and vice versa as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var englishToFrench = {
    'He': 'il',
    'throws': 'jete',
    'the': 'la',
    'ball': 'balle',
   }

   var frenchToEnglish = {
    'il': 'He',
    'jete': 'throws',
    'la': 'the',
    'balle': 'ball',
  }
var sourceText;
```

What I was planning to do was use two functions. One that splits the object inputs one by one and the other function is to translate them one by one. My work so far is as follows:

```
    var translateText = function() {
    var translationType = document.getElementById('translation').value;

    if (translationType === 'englishToFrench') {
        console.log('translation used: English to French');
        return 'code1';
    }else if(translationType === 'frenchToEnglish'){
        console.log('translation used: French to English');
        return 'code2';
    }else{
        return "No valid translation selected.";
    }
  };
```

My second function is:

```
        var translateBtnClickHandler = function() {
    var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;

    document.getElementById('targetText').value = translateText();

};

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
};


    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My problem here is linking the split function with the translating function. Assuming the everything else is fine, with HTML, how can I close this gap? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ? Which portion of `js` is not returning expected results ?

Comment: Try editing original Question to include `html` , instead of comment . What is "split function" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your functions into one function by checking your translation type and getting value to display like following

```
var englishToFrench = {
    'He': 'il',
    'throws': 'jete',
    'the': 'la',
    'ball': 'balle'
};

var frenchToEnglish = {
    'il': 'He',
    'jete': 'throws',
    'la': 'the',
    'balle': 'ball'
};
var translateBtnClickHandler = function () {
    var dictionary;
    var translationType = document.getElementById('translation').value;

    //get dictionary type
    if (translationType === 'englishToFrench') {
        dictionary = englishToFrench;
    }else if(translationType === 'frenchToEnglish'){
        dictionary = frenchToEnglish;
    }else{
        dictionary = false;
    }

    //if dictionary type is valid, get value from dictionary and display 
    if(dictionary) {
        var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;
        var translateText = dictionary[sourceText];
        document.getElementById('targetText').value = undefined ? "" : translateText;
    }

}
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
};
```

Comment: If I wanted to loop through **englishToFrench** and **frenchToEnglish** to display each element consecutively, i.e. "He throws the ball" as "il jete la balle" instead of typing in each word. I know I need a loop function but I'm not sure where to implement. Sorry, I'm just beginner

Comment: After you get sourceText, 
- split it into array by using space as delimiter
- loop through the array element, translate, and concat to a temporary string
- display your translated text

* write after  var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText').value;

Answer (score 0):

Try passing `sourceText` to `translateText` , using `String.prototype.match()` , `String.prototype.replace()` to match , replace words in first `textarea` element

```js
var englishToFrench = {
  'He': 'il',
  'throws': 'jete',
  'the': 'la',
  'ball': 'balle',
}

var frenchToEnglish = {
  'il': 'He',
  'jete': 'throws',
  'la': 'the',
  'balle': 'ball',
}

var translateText = function(src) {

  var translationType = document.getElementById('translation').value;
  // do translation
  var re = new RegExp(src.value.match(/\w+/g).join("|"), "g"),
    translate = function(type) {
      return src.value.replace(re, function(match) {
        return window[type][match] || match
      });
    };

  if (translationType === 'englishToFrench') {
    console.log('translation used: English to French');
    return translate(translationType)
  } else if (translationType === 'frenchToEnglish') {
    console.log('translation used: French to English');
    return translate(translationType)
  } else {
    return "No valid translation selected.";
  }

};

var translateBtnClickHandler = function() {
  var sourceText = document.getElementById('sourceText');

  document.getElementById('targetText').value = translateText(sourceText);

};

window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('translateBtn').onclick = translateBtnClickHandler;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head lang="en">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>A simple translation app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>A simple tranlation app</h1>
  <div>
    <textarea id="sourceText">
    </textarea>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="translation">Choose:</label>
    <select id="translation" name="translation">
      <option>select a translation type</option>
      <option value="englishToFrench">English to French</option>
      <option value="frenchToEnglish">French to English</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="targetText" disabled="disabled"></textarea>
  </div>

  <button id="translateBtn" type="button">Translate</button>
</body>

</html>
```